# How to require location to be on for an app on marketplace download?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, location, privacy

I recently submitted a windows phone app to the marketplace that uses the geolocation api to grab the gps coordinates and do something with it.

I got declined in certification because I don't ask for the users permission to use location.

My first thought was to just show a message box in the app and if they hit cancel then don't let them use it. But I noticed that a lot of marketplace apps somehow have that dialog box popup when you download the app.

How do they make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the application has the `ID_CAP_LOCATION` capability then the market place client (web and phone) will prompt the user to accept the location policy. Note: Including or removing  this capability from your `WMAppManifest.xml` file only effects developer phones. When your application is ingested into the market place it scans your XAP to determine its actual capabilities and applies those automatically.

However in order to be ingested into the market place you must provide the user with the ability to disable location services, a location privacy policy and the user must **opt in** to using location services. ie. Disable location services until they've said to use them.

The [Application Certification Requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) spell this out as requirements [2.7 through to 2.7.8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Also, note, the testers are pretty thorough in this regard and will fail your application if it does not have such features. Additionally they will test your application when location services have been opted out - both at the application level (via the mechanism you provide) and at the Operating System level (Settings > Location > Off). Make sure you test these scenarios as the second one bit me and caused my first submission to be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the WMAppManifest.xml and add

```
<Capabilities>
....
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
```